# Magento 1.5, Adding orderstatuses "programmatically"

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In magento < 1.5 one could add orderstatuses in extensions via config.xml.
Since magento 1.5 there is an admin interface for this, hence the above approach no longer works.

So how can I have my extension install a bunch of statuses?
And assign them to states, and set as default for a state?

Do I have to manually insert them into the sales_order_status and sales_order_status_state db-tables? If that is true, I have to update the "is_default" column as well..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new status:

```
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')
    ->setData(array(
        'label'   => 'New Status',
        'status'  => 'new_status',
    ))
;

try {
    $status->save();
} 
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```